# Converting textual datasets to numerical datasets

Tags: matlab, nlp, classification

Could I ask you please about converting datasets. I have 2 datasets, one for training and the other for testing. Both contains mixed features of texts and numbers about words in sentence. e.g. (indexes, tags, pos, ..etc).

this is an example of an instance in one of the datasets (.csv format):

1,point,6,1279,1284,point,NN,confluence,NN,would,MD,maps::NNS the::DT confluence::NN,NNS_DT DT_NN NNS_DT_NN,would::MD have::VB to::TO,MD_VB VB_TO MD_VB_TO,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,NPe,PLACE

What I want to do is to train these datasets using neural networks in Matlab and extract deep features from it. The problem is that Matlab is dealing only with numerical datasets. Also, I'm using some classifiers in java and they are working only with numbers not texts.

Any one have a suggestion please how to train such datasets? or how to convert it to numerical format with regards to numerical features in it??

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

By casting the variable using the function `double()` you will get an array of all the letters with the corresponding code number.

For example `double('MA1LAB')` will output

```
ans =

77    65    49    76    65    66
```

Then, you can deal with each letter with its corresponding code.

Please note that each letter gets a code, so 1279 will be dealt with as 4 characters.

Comment: I'm not looking for this type of converting. By using this method, I will lose all semantics of texts. e.g. "go" and "run" are both motion verbs, but by converting using casting, they will be far from each other.